# meteor reactive client code: asking for best / right practise of writing code

Tags: javascript, meteor

Attached you find an example of client code: handling a jQuery simple slider which can changed its value by manual dragging or getting new values from server by message stream.

On Template.SLIDER.rendered event, I create the jQuery UI Slider on a Div element.

I save a reference var to the Div element in var Div_Slider

I did this, because I have to update the slider value also by event from server (here by stream notification)

I subscribed to the reactive Session var "slider_value" by Deps.autorun().

When Session.set is called, event should also update the Slider.value if this element was already rendered.

Instead using $('#servo-slide'). more than once and have to inspect the DOM again and again I prepared this local Div_Slider var as a reference and use it during interaction with the jQuery UI Slider.

**Q: Is this the best and perfomant technic?** - Creating local .js file scope vars to reference to commonly used elements?

**Q: Do you have any suggestion to my sample code?**

```js
    { ... }

    /*
       --------------- Slider
    */

    // save reference to slider
    var Div_Slider = undefined;

    // be reactive on Session value slider_value
    Deps.autorun(function () {
      // we just operate when available
      if (Session.equals('slider_value', undefined)) 
        return;
      // be reactive on slider_value
      var slider_value = Session.get('slider_value');
      // set jQuery slider position
      if (!_.isUndefined(Div_Slider)) {
        Servo_Slider.slider({value: slider_value});
      }
    });

    // listen to the stream
    notifications.on('change_slider_value', function(new_value) {
      // we are updating the sliders value, this will also update the Session value in onChange event
      Session.set("slider_value", new_value);
    });

    Template.SLIDER.rendered = function () {
      // save reference to elements
      Div_Slider = $(this.find('#servo-slide'));

      // update div as slider
      Servo_Slider.slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        range: "min",
        value: Session.get("slider_value"),
        change:
          function(event, ui) {
            // only do something if the event was generated here
            if (event.originalEvent) {
              // do your actions
            }
          }
      });
    }

    { ... }
```

Comment: Looks fine. Maybe consider rate-limiting notifications from the server. Also look at stopping computations from `Deps.autorun` when the template is no longer in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Nathans comment and answer on another question from me, I optimized the code and report best case writing meteor code for jQuery slider.

---

```js
    // listen to the stream
    notifications.on('change_slider_value', function(new_value) {
      // we are updating the sliders value, this will also update the Session value in onChange event
      Session.set("slider_value", new_value);
    });

    Template.SLIDER.rendered = function () {
      // save reference to elements
      var slider = $(this.find('#servo-slide'));

      // update div as slider
      slider.slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        range: "min",
        value: Session.get("slider_value"),
        change:
          function(event, ui) {
            // only do something if the event was generated here
            if (event.originalEvent) {
              // do your actions
            }
          }
      });

      // be reactive on Session value slider_value
      this.computation = Deps.autorun(function () {
        // set jQuery slider position
        slider.slider({value: Session.get('slider_value')});
      });
    }

    Template.SLIDER.destroyed = function () {
      // check if we added a computation and stop
      if (this.computation) 
        this.computation.stop();
    }
```